# How to store and organize data visibility(Public/Private/OnlyFriends) in database

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to build a small social network, and I want to provide to my users the ability of controlling their data Visibility/Privacy, just like Facebook ...

For example they can make their Data (*Pseudo,City,Birthday,Gender,...*) **Private** , **Public** or **OnlyFriends** ...

I have already built user tables: user, user_profiles, ...

```
create table user(
    id int unsigned not null auto_increment,
    pseudo varchar(64) not null,
    password char(64) not null,
    lname varchar(48) not null,
    fname varchar(48) not null,
    gender char(1) not null,
    --Other fields
    primary key(id),
    unique(pseudo)
);

create table user_profile(
    uid int unsigned not null,
    birthday date,
    phone varchar(15),
    address varchar(255),
    city varchar(64),
    postal_code varchar(10),
    -- ... Other fields
);
```

For storing those Visibility data I Have tried this :

```
create table data_visibility(
    id smallint unsigned not null auto_increment,
    name char(15) not null,
    primary key(id),
    unique(name)
);

create table user_visibility(
    uid int unsigned not null,
    pseudo smallint not null,
    lname smallint not null,
    fname smallint not null,
    email smallint not null,
    gender smallint not null,
    birthday smallint not null,
    -- ... Other fields
    primary key(uid),
    foreign key(uid) references user(id) on delete cascade on update cascade,
    foreign key(pseudo) references data_visibility(id),
    foreign key(lname) references data_visibility(id),
    foreign key(fname) references data_visibility(id)
    -- ... Other foreigns
);
```

But I'm not comfortable with this solutions if I alter user table by adding new fields I will need to update user_visibility fields too, and all those foreign keys looks weird ...

What programmers do normally to solve this problem ?

Comment: I had a similar problem, i don't tell you it's the good way to operate but i simply didn't use foreign key for that type of operation. I had an Id and a group. Because it stays inside the code i just assumed it was always correct.

Comment: Yeah it looks that foreign keys just complicate things here, I think I have to remove data_visibility table ...